# How to Convert NSNumber to CBUUID in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, type-conversion, bluetooth-lowenergy, uuid, nsnumber

I have a device UDID which is a [NSNumber](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumber_Class/).

I need to convert it to [CBUUID](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBUUID_Class/).

How can I convert?

Comment: How do you get a device UDID as an `NSNumber`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSNumber *aNumber = @123456;   
CBUUID *cUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:[aNumber stringValue]];
```